# 24 hour in SimpleDateFormat() and milliseconds in java

Tags: java, date, time, format

I am building a DAQ software and right now I am in the process of creating a log file. I thought of showing the time on each entry. A simple code(that cannot compile) is the following

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class daq(){

    SimpleDateFormat now = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");

    public void go(){
        report.setProperty("INSERT", "["+now.format(new Date())+"] Acquisition Started\n");
    }
    public void init(){
        report.setProperty("INSERT", "["+now.format(new Date())+"] ADC Channel 1: Read Complete\n");
        report.setProperty("INSERT", "["+now.format(new Date())+"] Initialisation Complete\n");
    }
    public void stop(){
        report.setProperty("INSERT", "["+now.format(new Date())+"] Acquisition Stopped\n");
    }

}
```

A typical result of the above "code" is the following

```
[06:30:09] Acquisition Started
[06:30:09] ADC Channel 1: Read Complete
[06:30:09] Initialisation Complete
[06:30:13] Acquisition Stopped
```

I was wondering if there is a way to display the time in 24 hour format(i.e. `18:30:09` instead of `06:30:09`)?

Is there also a way to display milliseconds? A format like `hh:mm:ss:mils`? I tried to use `sss` instead of `ss` but I only get a `0` for the first `s`. An example output is

```
[21:50:004] Acquisition Started
[21:50:004] ADC Channel 1: Read Complete
[21:50:004] Initialisation Complete
[21:50:013] Acquisition Stopped
```

Comment: 06:30:09PM is equivalent to 18:30:09, not to 16:30:09 ;)

Comment: @Julien: Oops!!! I'll correct it!!! Thank's!!!

Comment: I mentionned this to prevent you from searching why you got 18 where you expected 16 ;)

Comment: @Julien: I actually expected 18, so it wouldn't be a matter! Thank's anyway!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this :-

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss:SSS");
```

[Also read this.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)
Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 6):

You should use `HH` instead of `hh`:

```
SimpleDateFormat now = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
```

Comment: @Thanos Have you gone through the documentation of `SimpleDateFormat`? You'll get all the formats there. BTW, for milliseconds you use `SSS`.

Comment: I have already tried `sss` but I don't actually get what I want. Please check my edited question.

Answer (score 0):

## Time Zone

The question and answers ignore the issue of time zones. Usually it is best to do logging in UTC (no time zone offset) to avoid ambiguity and to avoid confusion over Daylight Saving Time.

## ISO 8601

The sensible ISO 8601 standard defines a format for textual representation of date-time values. This format is especially useful in logging.

## Joda-Time

The Joda-Time library supports time zones, has a built-in constant for UTC time zone, and uses the ISO 8601 format and it's 24-hour clock by default.

```
String output = DateTime.now( DateTimeZone.UTC ).toString();
```