# Converting java sql timestamp to String

Tags: java

Im having a little trouble converting a sql timestamp to string, their outputs are different.

```
@Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date auctionStart;

public void setTime(){
    SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
    String aucStartString = f.format(auctionStart);


}
```

My auctionStart date prints: 04-Apr-2017 17:14:10
When i convert it to string it prints: 2017-04-04 05:14:10

It looks like the hours are converting to 12 hour format, any ideas how to correct it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [24 hour in SimpleDateFormat() and milliseconds in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22230826/24-hour-in-simpledateformat-and-milliseconds-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `H` instead of `h` for the hours as from [`Class SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) javadoc.

- H Hour in day (0-23)  Number  0
- k Hour in day (1-24)  Number  24
- K Hour in am/pm (0-11)    Number  0
- h Hour in am/pm (1-12)    Number  12

  `SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");`

**UPDATE**

```
Date auctionStart = new Date(2017-1900,4,4,17,14,10);

    SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    String aucStartString = f.format(auctionStart);
    System.out.println(aucStartString);
```

Prints

```
2017-05-04 17:14:10
```

Comment: thanks for your help but it is still printing as 2017-04-04 05:14:10 with adding HH

Comment: impossible. double check my answer please

Comment: Yes, apologies must not have compiled first try, Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Per the [SimpleDateFormat javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), you want

```
SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Edited because I originally put 'kk' instead of 'HH' which is most likely not what you want.
'kk' shows hour as 1-24 while 'HH' shows hour as the more common 0-23.